# compile eclipses multi project imported in intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've imported a project that holds a lot of inter-dependent eclipse projects (around 30) into Intellij.

It worked out amazingly well. Each project is a module inside the Intellij, and the eclipse meta files are properly parsed so the dependencies are recognized correctly in Intellij. The only problem is related to compiling. I have to compile modules ([Shift] + [CTRL] + [F9]) manually in the order of dependencies.

Is there a way to automate or configure the order of module compilation in Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified on Jetbrain website. you can refer following link for the same:

[how to access the compiler settings, modify the list of recognized resources, exclude certain paths from compilation, select the desired compiler, and configure annotation processing.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/configuring-compiler-settings.html?origin=old_help)

Comment: yeps, seems that its there, the module compilation order should be defined by the order that they are listed in the dependencies tab https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/dependencies.html#order_of_dependencies